# Why are public keys not public and need to be requested from the wallet holder?

Tags: wallets, public-key, protocol

What are some potential problems with storing public keys of wallets once they are revealed?

Otherwise, I would imagine the public key of most user wallets will be available in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing revealed public keys is less secured as public keys are used by the wallet to create different addresses. Wallet addresses are hashed version of the public keys and are more secured and can be shared publicly by anyone.

However, you can actually send crypto directly to the public key, but wallet addresses are shorter in forms and have a standard (hashed and padded) for them, whereas none for public keys.

Comment: thank you! How does revealing the public key present a vulnerability; is it bad for others to know more addresses you can generate?

Comment: Revealing the public keys may make one more traceable and less anonymous, as public key is highly characteristic and from a privacy standpoint, you don't want others to know and track the addresses you created.  See: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/48423/is-it-bad-to-expose-the-public-key